# Unnest list and concatenate in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I wish to unnest (flatten?) and concatenate strings (comma separated) of text within a `tibble`. Example data:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(person = c("Alice", "Bob", "Mary"), 
          score = list(c("Red", "Green", "Blue"), c("Orange", "Green", "Yellow"), "Blue"))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  person score    
  <chr>  <list>   
1 Alice  <chr [3]>
2 Bob    <chr [3]>
3 Mary   <chr [1]>
```

Expected output:

```
tibble(person = c("Alice", "Bob", "Mary"),
       score = c("Red, Green, Blue", "Orange, Green, Yellow", "Blue" ))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  person score                
  <chr>  <chr>                
1 Alice  Red, Green, Blue     
2 Bob    Orange, Green, Yellow
3 Mary   Blue
```

I suspect there's a very neat `tidyverse` solution to this but I've been unable to find an answer after extensive searching; I suspect I'm using the wrong search terms (unnest/concatentate).
A `tidyverse` solution would be preferred. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way would be to `unnest` the data in long format and collapse it by group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::unnest(score) %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  summarise(score = toString(score))

# person score                
#  <chr>  <chr>                
#1 Alice  Red, Green, Blue     
#2 Bob    Orange, Green, Yellow
#3 Mary   Blue
```

---

Other option would be `rowwise`

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(score = toString(score))
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, this looks good! Perhaps I ought to make this a whole new question but; how could I generalise your method above to `unnest()` on _all_  columns in a `tibble` which are lists? e.g. if my df is 100 columns wide and 12 are lists, how could I pull out these columns and send them to `toString()`?

Comment: @Simon In that case I think `rowwise` solution is better with `mutate_at`,Select all the columns in `vars` and apply the function `df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with('score')), toString)`

Comment: Is there a method to just select columns which are lists? In a large df it can be difficult to know ahead of time which columns are lists (without manually trawling through each column and making a note). Using `starts_with` assumes that you know the name of all list colums ahead of time. Thanks!

Comment: @Simon yes, you can use `mutate_if `, `df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate_if(is.list, toString)`

Answer (score 9):

You can do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(score = map_chr(score, toString))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  person score                
  <chr>  <chr>                
1 Alice  Red, Green, Blue     
2 Bob    Orange, Green, Yellow
3 Mary   Blue
```

If you have multiple list columns you can do:

```
df <- tibble(person = c("Alice", "Bob", "Mary"), 
       score1 = list(c("Red", "Green", "Blue"), c("Orange", "Green", "Yellow"), "Blue"),
       score2 = rev(list(c("Red", "Green", "Blue"), c("Orange", "Green", "Yellow"), "Blue")))

df %>%
  mutate_if(is.list, ~ map_chr(.x, toString))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  person score1                score2               
  <chr>  <chr>                 <chr>                
1 Alice  Red, Green, Blue      Blue                 
2 Bob    Orange, Green, Yellow Orange, Green, Yellow
3 Mary   Blue                  Red, Green, Blue
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution 1:

```
df$score <- sapply(df$score, toString)
```

Base R solution 2:

```
df$score <- unlist(lapply(df$score, paste, collapse = ", "))
```

Data:

```
df <- tibble(person = c("Alice", "Bob", "Mary"), 
       score = list(c("Red", "Green", "Blue"), c("Orange", "Green", "Yellow"), "Blue"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-size-fits-all approach with (recent) Tidyverse, which doesn't interfere with grouping:

```
df %>% mutate(across(where(is.list), ~ sapply(., toString)))
```